# DocuSign eSignature REST API C# Client : Can the same template role perform multiple signing steps on a single document?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

**Versions**

- Docusign C# Client- DocuSign.eSign.dll v3.1.5
- .NetFramework 4.7.1

**Our Requirement**

We need to implement a signing workflow where the same template role can perform multiple actions on the same document. A simplified example of this would be the following.

- Single Template (Document)
- Assigned a role called "Customer"
- Step 1 - Customer must sign
- Step 2 - Someone else must sign
- Step 3 - Customer must view document
- Signing workflow completed

Below is a diagram from the DocuSign eSignature admin console where "CC" represents the Customer template role

[image: DocuSign Signing Order Diagram For Template]

**Some example Code**

Our application uses the C# Docusign Client (which is essentially a wrapper for Http Requests that need to be sent to the Docusign API) to tell DocuSign the ID of the template (Document) we need to populate and the name/email address of each recipient that has a role in the signing workflow.

```cs
var envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
    AllowRecipientRecursion = "true",
    TemplateId = templateId,
    TemplateRoles = peopleWithRolesOnTheTemplate.Select(person => new TemplateRole
    {
        RoleName = person.Role, // e.g "Customer"
        Name = person.Name,
        Email = person.Email
        // etc etc
    }).ToList(),
    Status = "sent"
};

var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient.Configuration);
var result = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(AccountId, envelope);
```

**Expected Result**

- Our application has specified the name and email address for the "Customer" template role and sent a request to create an envelope to DocuSign
- We expect the resulting DocuSign envelope to have 3 signing steps, 2 of them belonging to the Customer template role.
- We expect each step belong to the Customer role to be populated with the name and email address we specified in the code snippet above.
- We expect the Customer role to receive the document TWICE, once to sign and the second time to view the document AFTER the recipient in Signing step 2 has signed.

**Actual Result**

- Customer Signs document, Second Recipient signs document, Customer **is not** sent document to view (step 3 not carried out)
- Looking at some of the DocuSign logging, it seems like there are only TWO signing steps in the envelope, not 3. **It's almost as if because two of the signing steps have the same role name, they are being merged into one signing step, of something along those lines.**

**My Questions**

1. Does anyone know if the above bolded statement is correct?
2. Is there ANY WAY we can use this DocuSign C# Client to create an envelope where the SAME ROLE can perform multiple signing steps? Or does each signing step in DocuSign have to belong to a separate role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the customer two role names: customerSigner and customerCC.

When you use the template, you will set three roles:

- customerSigner
- someoneElseSigner
- customerCC

The name and email for the first and third roles will be the same.

Also, DocuSign automatically (by default) sends a copy of the completed documents to the signers--so I'm not sure that you even need the cc role/step.

Finally, you said that

> Customer must view document

To ensure that the customer has seen the documents in step 3 you may want to use the certified delivery recipient.

Comment: Big thanks for that Larry, I will need to look into the certified delivery recipient to see how it works, but I am very happy with the answer you have given.